# How to fix OBJ file after import? (see pictures)

Tags: import, obj

I purchased this model last week, now I tried to import it into Blender and it looks like a lot of dots. How to fix it?

It looks like tiny faces or something. It's an OBJ.

[image: full model]

[image: full model]

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly about this object you want to "fix". My first guess could be that you expected polygons and not a point cloud, but it could just as well be that you expected a point cloud but there is something wrong with this particular point cloud. Can you clarify what exactly you would want to be different about this model?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: (1) Try using the "Wavefront (obj) (legacy)" importer. (2) Try using Blender 3.5 alpha version; some bugs related to missing faces were fixed a few months ago IIRC. (3) Otherwise, open the .obj in a text editor and check that there actually are faces (they would be lines that start with an `f`).

Comment: I checked it for faces (there are faces) and tried to import using legacy but now it not opening at all and showing me python error, i can attach it to post if you want, just dont know what to do with it

Comment: Did you try 3.5 alpha? There's likely a problem with the .obj file but since it's a commercial model that you can't share it's going to be very hard to say what it is. You could try opening it in another program like MeshLab. If that works you could export it and import the new file into Blender.

Comment: 3.5.0. alpha helped but one element in model still has same problem, meshlab opened only part of model.